# ¿Como cambiar de formato del timestamp de laravel?

Tags: laravel, date

he estado investigando pero no di con la respuesta, aunque la pregunta sea obvia no encuentro la solucion.

Lei la documentacion de Laravel y me fije que desde la version 7 implementaron por defecto en el timestamp(created_at, updated_at) el formato "U", por lo que una fecha: "2021-02-19 13:15:00" seria "2021-02-19T18:15:00.000000Z".

Lo que quiero es la primera fecha con ese formato, asi que para cambiarlo deberia agregar `protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';`, pero esto no me funciona, nose el motivo ya que al recuperar los datos siguen teniendo la otra fecha.

Hay 2 formas de recuperacion de datos que implemento

1. AJAX: Realizo la solicitud al servidor y recupero la informacion (Con esto me devuelve el formato "2021-02-19T18:15:00.000000Z")
2. Usando Blade: Solo agrego un `foreach` para recuperar la informacion, recorriendo e indicando `$item->created_at`, me devuelve "2021-02-19 13:15:00". **Sin haber puesto `protected $dateFormat` en el modelo**

Por *no me funciona*, me refiero a que simplemente ignora el formato

Estoy utilizando Laravel 8. Gracias a todos!

Comment: Prueba poniendo el atributo en la propiedad $casts de tu modelo. [Ref](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting). La propiedad $dateFormat solo se aplica al guardar en BD

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ perfecto es eso, pero tendria que colocarlo en todos mis modelos? O hay una configuracion general?

Comment: Mmm... tendría que buscar.. Lo que se me ocurre es que te hagas un modelo `CustomModel`, por ejemplo, donde hagas el cast de las fechas, y extiendas tus otros modelos desde ese, en vez de desde `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229370/laravel-eloquent-change-date-timestamps-global-to-d-m-y-his) una respuesta en inglés donde se propone eso que te digo, y muestra también otra opción usando un trait

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ investigare eso (nose que son traits) y vere esa solucion, gracias!

Comment: traits son como "pedazos" de código de clases que se pueden usar en muchas clases, pero no se pueden instanciar por si mismo ni heredar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con respecto al uso de la propiedad `$dateFormat`: no la uses. Es para la comunicación entre el modelo y la BBDD y no del modelo hacia la capa de negocio o la lógica de dominio. La documentación tiene un error que [ha suscitado más de un malentendido](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/dateformat-mutator-not-working), pero suele zanjarse cuando alguien dice: "*si encontraste un error, manda un pull request con la corrección*".

El comportamiento heterogéneo entre lo que ves en blade y lo que ves por ajax es que el backend obedece al tipo de respuesta que la petición espera.

- Si la respuesta espera que le devuelvan JSON, entonces se invoca `$instancia->toJSON()`. Ese método eventualmente llega a los campos de fecha y al invocar `$instancia->created_at->toJson()` la salida es ISO-8601
- Si ocupas el campo para interpolar en una plantilla, lo que es invoca es `$instancia->created_at->__toString()`, cuya salida obedece en cambio al formato
  `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

En [este playground](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/95fa8f61-d8ac-43f4-99d1-15b5f545ac46) podrás comprobar que el comportamiento normal es tal como te ha pasado.

```
$now=\Carbon\Carbon::now();

dump([
  'toJson'=>$now->toJSON(),
  '__toString'=>$now->__toString()
]);

array:2 [▼
  "toJson" => "2021-02-20T23:19:52.745229Z"
  "__toString" => "2021-02-20 23:19:52"
]
```

Para formatear explícitamente la presentación de tus fechas se debe usar la propiedad `$casts` que permite  declarar no sólo para las fechas sino para cualquier otro campo, físico o computado, la máscara de formato.

En [este playground dejé otro ejemplo](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/4b19ee31-8c61-4410-ae48-5f8bb5b80f60), consistente en un modelo cuyos casts dicen:

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s' ,
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:D, d M Y H' ,
    'verdadero_o_falso'=> 'bool',
    'edad'=>'int'
];
```

Si creo una instancia como:

```
$instancia=new ModeloCualquiera([
  'created_at'=>now()->subDay(),
  'updated_at'=>now(),
  'verdadero_o_falso'=>1,
  'edad'=>'75.33'
]);
```

fíjate que las fechas son distintas, el 1 pasó a ser booleano y el string que puse en edad, a un entero. Todo esto con una tabla que ni siquiera existe.

```
dump($instancia->toArray());

array:4 [▼
  "created_at" => "2021-02-20 00:00:30"
  "updated_at" => "Sun, 21 Feb 2021 00"
  "verdadero_o_falso" => true
  "edad" => 75
]
```

Si tú quieres que todos tus modelos usen la misma máscara, lo más sano es heredar de un mismo modelo abstracto.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


abstract class ModeloBase extends Model {
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s' ,
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s' 
    ];
}
```

En todos los demás modelos, donde decían `extends Model` ahora debe decir `extends ModeloBase`.

El problema con el uso de un trait, en este caso, es que hay una lógica de precedencia a la hora de redeclarar métodos (la clase manda, luego los traits que usa, luego la clase padre), incorporada al lenguaje en el  [RFC: Traits](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/traits) y refrendada luego en el [RFC: Horizontal Reuse](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/horizontalreuse#precedence_order). **Esa lógica** no cubre propiedades. Ya que el modelo base de Eloquent tiene un valor para `$casts` lo siguiente tira error:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait MascaraFecha {
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s' ,
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:D, d M Y H' ,
        'verdadero_o_falso'=> 'bool',
        'edad'=>'int'
    ];
}
class ModeloCualquiera extends Model {
    use MascaraFecha;
}
```

> Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model and MascaraFecha define the same property ($casts) in the composition of ModeloCualquiera. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible

Comment: Hasta hace poco no conocía los `cast` y `traits` pero a medida que lba aprendiendo me di cuenta que me simplificaron bastante las cosas, sobre el `datetime` me dejo claro tu explicación y vere si utilizar o no los `traits`, gracias!