# Problemas con fecha laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Resulta que tengo un campo `fecha_venta` de tipo timestamp en postgres en laravel tengo el modelo Venta lo así:

```
use Jenssegers\Date\Date;    
public function getFechaVentaAttribute($date)
        {
            return new Date($date);
        }
```

En mi controller cuando obtengo `return Venta::find(1);` me retorna el campo `fecha_venta` como `2021-03-12T01:45:13.000000Z` y otro campo más que tengo el cual `no aplico mutators` en el modelo me muestra así: `2021-03-11 20:45:13` y esto es lo correcto, así está en la BD, el campo `fecha_venta` aunmenta 1 día más el cual es incorrecto, ¿por que lo hace?

En el archivo `app.php` en laravel 5.8 lo tengo configurado así:  `'timezone' => 'America/Lima','locale' => 'es',` la configuracion regional de mi PC también está de la misma manera, no entiendo por que pasa eso.

Comment: No aumenta 1 día más, sólo unas horas, las mismas que hay de diferencia horaria entre UTC y el sistema. El campo `fecha_venta` te muestra la fecha según zona horaria UTC. En cambio el otro campo se muestra según la zona horaria del sistema. Revisa la configuración de servidor y cliente y ajusta según sea necesario.

Comment: la Z al final del formato ISO significa UTC.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, mira tengo instalado XAMPP con PHP v7.4.1 y en la parte de `date.timezone="America/Lima"` en la PC lo tengo formato Regional como español Peru

Comment: @frijjolitto entonces ya respondieron a tu pregunta no? El porque sale asi la fecha

Comment: @JuanRivera Si pero les decía que si revisé esos parámetros que indican aún así sigue saliendo mal la fecha o bueno lo transforma a un formato que no corresponde en este caso a UTC lo correcto sería a `America/Lima`.

Pero he realizado la siguiente prueba:
PHP Puro: `echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); // 13-03-2021 14:51:06`
Carbon: `return Carbon::now(); // 2021-03-13T19:51:09.411786Z`

La misma diferencia, como debo de configurar o setear a Carbon para que utilice el timezone de mi php.ini?
intenté con esto y nada 
 `date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');
        return Carbon::now();`

Comment: @frijjolitto si quieres formatear tal vez esto pueda servirte: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/429514 funciona también en laravel 5.8

Answer (score 0):

Hola Amigo yo lo solucione de la siguiente manera usando la funcion propia de php date_default_timezone_set(); en donde le establece una zona horaria en tu caso seria 'America/Lima' de todas manera aqui tienes la documencion de las zonas que horarias que puedes escojer [zonas-horaria](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

en un ejemplo aplicando un appends en laravel seria asi, ojo la desventaja de este metodo es que cada parte donde manipules fechas tendras que establecer la zona horaria desde el principio del codigo

```
public function getDiasAlertaAttribute()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');
    
    $formatted_dt1=Carbon::parse($this->fecha_elaborada);

    $formatted_dt2 =Carbon::parse(Carbon::create(null, null, null));

    $diasAlerta = $formatted_dt1->diffInDays($formatted_dt2);        

    return $diasAlerta;
}
```